# User Permission levels to view certain informaton on a Calendar (sharepoint 2013)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-calendar

This question has been with me for a while and tried to come up with my own solution but unable to get it done without your help / advise.

**The Objective:**

To create a calendar where all departments can enter their Holidays | Meetings | Birthdays | Business | Visitors etc. but with the exception that certain information such as Birthday's to be restricted only to their own department.

**Current Status**

Currently, as we all know, each user has got its own calendar in Outlook where their maintain their own meetings etc etc.

if somebody wants to find out when I am on holiday, they can simply pull up my calendar in Outlook and boooooom they see all my meetings / holidays etc.

**What is the Idea?**

Well, maybe I am overthinking this way too much but I thought maybe having one central calendar in SharePoint (and have it synchronised with Outlook) where all users can enter their holidays/meetings etc but then limiting the access to see certain stuff to each department etc.

Is this even possible and if so, is it worth it really!?
Maybe, this is way out of the scope ... ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

Add two additional columns to the Calendar. 
Name:Birthday Type:Checkbox 
Name:Department  Type:User (Set Show field to Department)

For a Birthday item - users tick the box for birthday and enter the name of the "Birthday user"

In the all items view - filter the view to not show birthday items.

To show birthdays relevant to a department
Add this calendar `webpart` to a new page and configure the view to show birthday items only and where field department is equal to `[Me]`.

This solution should meet your requirements.

Comment: hmmmm good approach actually :) will have to try this out. cheers